# Could sawtooth waveform be optimal for transformer input?

Tags: transformer, theory, waveform

All the transformer theory I have reviewed uses sinusoidal waveforms, and concludes that a true sinusoidal input is optimal.  But I'm wondering whether a sawtooth waveform would actually be optimal in practice?

Theory depends frequently on the differentiability of the waveform, so it's "convenient" to neglect sawtooths because they are not differentiable when voltage changes direction.  However, I assume that:

1. It would be relatively easy in practice to produce an input from a DC power source that is a clean sawtooth.
2. A transformer would *not* suffer from the "harmonic noise" that might be suggested by an abstract attempt to approximate a sawtooth as a sum of higher-frequency sine curves.

On the other hand, one reason I imagine the sawtooth might *not* be optimal is the magnetic hysteresis of transformer cores: If that's large enough then the slow reversal of a sine wave could in fact optimize the transmission of power.

Comment: Optimal in what sense? An "ideal" transformer is already optimal, so obviously you're thinking of various secondary or parasitic effects in "real" transformers. Which ones do you have in mind, and why does a sawtooth address those specifically?

Comment: Why do you say that a transformer wouldn't have issues with the higher harmonics? A sawtooth (technically) implies an infinite sum of harmonics, and therefore requires a transformer with infinite frequency response. Any realistic transformer will not be able to handle higher harmonics, and there will be some loss there.

Comment: It's arguable that a square wave is optimal for a transformer, so 'always' working at maximum voltage and maximum current. The abrupt voltage step does not trouble the core magnetics, only the parasitic capacitances of the winding.

Comment: @Neil_UK - Yes, I guess that makes even more sense, but only as the frequency approaches infinity, right?

Comment: @DaveTweed et. al. - Transformers don't "work" when voltage is held constant.  Since the change in voltage drives the transformation it seems like the "first guess" would be that you want a constant change in voltage, and anything else would be sub-optimal.  In fact, we know that in practice higher-frequency inputs allow for more efficient transformers (up to a point).  Whatever rate of voltage change a transformer is optimized for, a sawtooth maintains that rate over its entire period, whereas a sine wave only hits it for an instant every half cycle.

Comment: Ask yourself this: If it really was, then why don't you read everywhere that it is? Transformers aren't really a new technology...

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I did ask myself, and that's why I'm asking the question here.  I want to correct and/or deepen my understanding of this subject.  I am nowhere close to suggesting that accepted theory and practice are incorrect.  In fact, in the question itself I suggest a possible reason why my "first guess" might be wrong, but I don't know enough to validate that.

Comment: Just what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @feetwet read about voltage = dflux/dt, flux = int(voltage)dt, then re-read your question and my comment, and see what constant voltage and changing voltage imply.

Comment: @Neil_UK - Let's see: constant voltage implies non-zero flux that is constant over time.  I'm not sure what that indicates for a transformer: My understanding is a transformer only transmits power via a *change* in flux, which requires a change in voltage, right?

Comment: @feetwet No, this is where you don't understand transformer action, or Faraday's Law of Induction and Lenz's law (wikipedia). Constant voltage implies a constant **rate of change** of flux. Any constant flux, whether zero or finite, implies zero voltage. The two phases of action of a square wave would be a) voltage +ve, flux starts at -max, slews to +max then b) voltage -ve, flux slews back to -max c) repeat. And yes, the change in flux (so a finite voltage on the windings for a while, then reverse to avoid going to infinite flux) is necesary for power transfer

Comment: @Neil_UK - But a true square wave has *instantaneous* slew.  So mathematically it transmits infinite power for an infinitesimal dt, and otherwise (while holding the voltage before reversing polarity) it transmits zero power?  Anyway, that's why I thought sawtooth instead of square would be optimal.  But again, I'm asking because neither of these scenarios lend themselves to the standard analysis, so I'm wondering if at some point the *realities* of transformers show that even if you could produce a very crisp square or sawtooth it would be suboptimal to a sine input.

Comment: @feetwet the reason sine is used for distribution is because generators lends themselves to sine generation, and 3 phase generation has constant torque on the generator when using sines. Sine is not optimal for transformers. I started my career 40 years ago designing transformers for money, and designed one as recently as 2 years ago for a major utility. I know what I'm talking about. Be modest, accept that square wave is optimum, try to figure out why. The infinite speed edges are a technical issue which can be omitted from a core-flux based analysis, however unphysical you feel it is.

Comment: @feetwet I'm not going to comment on this issue any more. You're on your own now. You can choose to learn, or argue. Well done for thinking on your own, but on this issue you have it wrong. Until you understand  (for yourself) why the sharp voltage edges are irrelevant for flux issues, and why square wave is optimum, you won't understand transformers. Hint, with a sine voltage signal, the flux is cosine. With a square voltage wave, the flux is triangle wave. Have fun.

Comment: @Neil_UK - I don't presume that I have it right, and I do want do develop a correct understanding of this.  I've tried to figure out why square would be optimal and clearly my already limited knowledge of this subject is not going to get me there.  For example, I don't see how flux can be "triangle" with a square frequency that exceeds whatever hysteresis inheres to the hardware.  But this isn't a "homework" question, so while I appreciate your encouragement to work it out, both I and this Q&A site would benefit from the full explanation someone with your experience can provide.

Comment: @feetwet there is no more explanation, unless you want me to explain calculus, which I'm not going to do. Every subject has a 'required pre-knowledge', and for EM theory, calculus is a major part of it. If you do understand calculus, go back to my post where I say voltage = d(flux)/dt and flux = integral(voltage)dt, and work forward from there. If you don't understand calculus, take a course in it, and then return to this problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK - Sure, bring on the calculus.  Years ago I *pwned* Stokes' theorem ;)  So, being a little more careful: What you're saying is that a constant voltage implies a constant change in flux over time.  My understanding is that power (or EMF) is transmitted through a transformer via change in flux.  If both of those statements are true, then a transformer should be able to transmit power *over time* by applying a constant voltage to one side.  Now that doesn't sound right.

Comment: @feetwet Both statements are true, but there is a practical problem. Flux cannot increase over time without bound, eventually the core will saturate. Apply a constant voltage, flux ramps up to +max, rate of change prop to voltage. At core saturation, flux cannot increase any more, induced voltage will drop to zero. We avoid this problem by reversing the input voltage before the core saturates, then reverse again before saturates in the other direction, and again. This is why transformers have a minimum frequency for any given voltage, the core has a Vs, volt.second max product specification.

Comment: @feetwet ...so if you had superconducting windings made from eludium (max current inifinity), and a core cast from solid unobtainium (max flux infinity), you **could** apply a DC voltage indefinitely and transmit power. But we have to work with copper and iron, so can only transmit power for a short time, before having to reverse the excitation. Note that **air** is not limited in saturation like iron, but to exploit that, we would still need to have a potentially infinite magnetising current, hence the problem with copper.

Comment: @Neil_UK - Now that is an excellent explanation!  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @feetwet Excellent. Now do you see why applying less than maximum voltage at any time is sub-optimal? Square wave mean voltage = max voltage. Sine wave mean voltage is about 0.7ish of max voltage. As you apply more voltage, you get to saturation quicker, so have to reverse more frequently. This is why high frequency transformers can shift more power per weight than low frequency (aircraft 400Hz vs 50Hz for iron, ferrite 10s of kHz).

Comment: @Neil_UK - Yes!  Once one realizes the voltage is inducing a flux in the core, and that the magnetic saturation rate and limit is a defining physical characteristic of a transformer, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Please combine your various comments into an actual answer, and then we can clean up the rather long comment chain on this post.

Comment: @DaveTweed sigh! I will need to look up how to do a latex integral ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The optimal input waveform, as far as the core flux is concerned, is a square wave. It turns out that while sine wave is a sub-optimal, because it's the 'natural' waveform for generation and for 3 phase power distribution, it is used as is.

The key to understanding inductors and transformers is to recognise that voltage and flux are linked, not proportionally, but through an integral, so flux = \$\int\! V \, \mathrm{d}t\$ and voltage = d(flux)/dt

If we apply a finite voltage to the primary of a transformer, the flux will begin to slew, at a rate proportional to the voltage. The changing flux will induce a voltage in the secondary, which can be used to drive a current through the load.

If we had magical materials to hand, so a core of unobtanium with infinite permeability usable to infinite flux, we could leave this DC voltage connected indefinitely, and the transformer would continue to transmit power, while the flux ramped continually upward, the magnetising current held to reasonable levels by the unreasonable core permeability.

Unfortunately, we have the practical problem that we need to use real materials, iron or ferrite, for the core, and these will eventually saturate. When that happens, the flux stops increasing, and the output voltage collapses to zero.

In order to avoid saturation, we reverse the input voltage just before the core saturates. With the reversed voltage, the flux slews back down again, through zero, and approaches saturation in the opposite direction. Reverse and repeat.

If the core were the only consideration, we could reverse the input voltage as quickly as we liked. All it would do at the core is alter (very quickly) the direction that the flux was slewing, the flux itself would be continuous. In practice, nothing can generate a very sharp edge, the capacitance of the windings would not permit a very sharp edge, and as long as the edge is 'much steeper' (say 10x steeper) than a sine wave, we will have the bulk of the efficiency improvement that we are looking for over a sine waveform.

Running a transformer at best efficiency, we will slew the flux from near -max flux to near +max flux. As the change in flux is the integral of voltage, any waveform that does this will have the same **mean** voltage over the half cycle. If a sine wave with a peak of 1 swings the flux over this range, then a square wave would need to have a peak of around 0.7 to have the same average.

The **power** delivered by the transformer into a resistive load depends on both the output voltage and the output current. With sine excitation, the current and voltage vary between 0 and max during the cycle. With square wave excitation, the voltage and current stay at the maximum level for essentially the whole cycle, so have a slightly higher power throughput.

Iron transformers on power networks tend to use the approximately sine-wave voltage transmitted. High frequency ferrite transformers, powered by switching devices from a DC bus, use the naturally produced square waves. Much more significant than the input waveform is the operating frequency, and the size of the core. It is almost never worth the bother of changing the input waveform from "what's easy" for the small gain that would result.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your two 'advantages' and see if they hold:

> It would be relatively easy in practice to produce an input from a DC power source that is a clean sawtooth.

Actually, that's very hard, especially if you need both a positive and a negative half. Nearly every active component has some non-linearity involved. Capacitors have an exponential voltage curve, inductors (of which transformers are a special case) have an exponentional current curve. Trying to make a linear increasing voltage or current is difficult. Even more difficult is to very quickly reverse the polarity at the falling edge of the sawtooth. Something your transformer won't like.

> A transformer would not suffer from the "harmonic noise" that might be suggested by an abstract attempt to approximate a sawtooth as a sum of higher-frequency sine curves.

I've got a surprise for you: a perfect sine curve does not have harmonics. Any other waveform is made of a series of sines (by the Fourier theorem), so definetely suffers from harmonics.

Comment: Good clarification on the first point.  I think you missed my second point: You can choose to analytically approximate (to an arbitrary epsilon) a sawtooth using a Fourier Transform, but is it certain that because an analytic approximation has harmonics (or any other characteristic) that the non-analytic function has those characteristics?  Obviously one characteristic the sawtooth does not have that a Fourier Transform does is differentiability at all points.

Answer (score 0):

> "Theory depends frequently on the differentiability of the waveform, so it's "convenient" to neglect sawtooths"

Not because it's convenient, but the only way of doing it is using a waveform that do not change between differentiations. You can take a look at [Faraday's Law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction). Differentiation is not optional.

One reason (the one I can think of) for using sinusoidal waves is that, although you can change phase and amplitude, you will always get the same waveform. You can take *sin(x)* as an example. It's derivative is *cos(x)*. The latter's derivative is *-sin(x)*. You can see that, as many times you derivate the waveform, it will always retain it's sinusoidal shape.

You can't do that with sawtooth. If you could derivate a sawtooth wave you would get a square wave, which can't drive another transformer. I guess the use of sinusoidal waves just makes everything easier. You can have many transformers in between the energy generation and the consumption.

Also,

> abstract attempt to approximate a sawtooth as a sum of higher-frequency sine curves

That might seem abstract enough for real life but it is a thing. Every time you listen to music and tell between the violin and the guitar, that's because a sum of particular higher-frequency sine curves (overtones) produces that single sound you can later recognize as a distinct instrument.

As I haven't studied transformer theory yet, I won't assume anything else.

Comment: I *think* you're restating my premise: You can't analytically apply Faraday's Law to undifferentiable curves.  I'm not negating that Law, but rather questioning whether an optimal solution to a system that involves it need be analytic.